# ICONV encoding differs between localhost and remote server

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, localhost, iconv

I have problem with encoding on localhosot and remote server. For example when I choose russian langueage on localhost show me "вторник 14.07.15"(correct answer) but on remote server "Р’С‚РѕСЂРЅРёРє 14.07.15".
In lang.ru.php is UTF-8 encoding and file looks like this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8', 'ru_RU', 'ru', 'rus', 'russian', 'ru_RU.ISO_8859-5', 'Russian_Russia.1251');

$lang = array();

$lang['code'] = "ru";

$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'Hello';
```

In index.php I show date:

```
echo "<span class='daydatetime'>" . iconv('Windows-1250', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT',strftime("%A <br> %d.%m.%y", strtotime("+ 1 days"))) . "</span>";
```

Why in localhost everything is all right and in remote server is broken encoding?
I would be very grateful if someone help me. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From php's setlocale page:

> If **locale** is an array or followed by additional parameters then each array element or parameter is tried to be set as new locale until success.

Calling setlocale and providing a number of locales with **different encodings** (ru_RU.UTF-8, ru_RU.ISO_8859-5) may not match the expectation in the iconv() call:

```
string iconv (string $in_charset, string $out_charset, string $str)
```

that the $in_charset is Windows-1250. You can get the server encoding by

```
$in_charset = nl_langinfo(CODESET);
```

Also $out_charset should match the charset in the Content-Type header.